# Does nginx have a Routing API?

Tags: nginx, routes

I am trying to see if nginx (OSS, not commercial) can be used not only as a load balancer, but as a network router/switch in the event that I need to shut my app down and redirect traffic to a CDN/static page, etc.

I was hoping to find a REST API that might allow me to configure routing rules on the fly but alas, I see nothing.

Does nginx provide this functionality out of the box? Or can I pair it with something that does? This would be a Java app it is balancing, and I see there is an [nginx-clojure](https://github.com/nginx-clojure/nginx-clojure) module. So perhaps I could expose a REST endpoint through Java (running on the nginx server) somehow...thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use nginx-clojure to do such work you need

- a java/clojure rewrite handler which is used as a router
- a java/clojure content handler which acts as a router API endpoint
- a shared map which is used to share state/rules among nginx worker processes (this is needed if the number of nginx worker processes > 1)

e.g.

## In nginx.conf

```nginx
## InitHandler is used to initialize shared map
jvm_init_handler_name my.InitHandler;

upstream myApp {
  .....
}

## requests will be redirected to upstream staticBackend when my app is down
upstream staticBackend {
 ....
}

server {

....

## share state/rules among nginx worker processes
shared_map routerRules tinymap?space=32k&entries=256;

## $mybackend will be changed by rewrite handler MyRouter
set $mybackend "";

location / {
  rewrite_handler_type java;
  rewrite_handler_name my.MyRouter;

  proxy_pass http://$mybackend;
}

location /restapi {
  content_handler_type java;
  content_handler_name my.MyRouterApi;
}

}
```

## In InitHandler.java

```java
public class InitHandler implements NginxJavaRingHandler {
  public static NginxSharedHashMap<String, String> rules;

  public Object[] invoke(Map<String, String> fakeRequest) {
     rules = NginxSharedHashMap.build("routerRules");
  }
}
```

## In MyRouter.java

```java
public class MyRouter implements  NginxJavaRingHandler {
   public Object[] invoke(Map<String, String> req) {
       String backend = InitHandler.rules.get("mybackend");
       if (backend == null) {
            backend = "myApp"; 
        }
       ((NginxJavaRequest)req).setVariable("mybackend", backend);
       return nginx.clojure.java.Constants.PHASE_DONE;
   }
}
```

## In MyRouterApi.java

```java
public class MyRouterApi implements  NginxJavaRingHandler {
   public Object[] invoke(Map<String, String> req) {

       String backend = req.get(MiniConstants.QUERY_STRING);

       /*chek backend ...... */

       //update the entry whose key is "mybackend" in the shared map
       InitHandler.rules.put("mybackend", backend);

        return new Object[] {200, null, "OK"};
   }
}
```

More docs can be found from https://nginx-clojure.github.io/ .

BTW the [embedding API](https://nginx-clojure.github.io/embed.html) will make dev/testing with nginx-clojure quite easy.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a great answer @xfeep (+1) - Two quick followup questions for you, if you don't mind! **(1)** Let's say that normally, `myApp` should load balance between `myapp01.example.org` and `myapp02.example.org`. And let's say that if I decide to re-route traffic to my static CDN, that the URL which should be served is `mycdn.example.org`. What do `upstream myApp`, `upstream staticBackend` and `MyRouterApi#invoke` now look like?

Comment: And **(2)** if the map is 32k in size and allows 256 entries, I assume that this leaves 128 bytes for each entry, yes? **What does each entry represent (an HTTP request?) and is 128 bytes adequate storage for it?**

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I lied! I have one last question as well (sorry!): **(3)** is it possible to use HTTPS and authentication (BasicAuth, JWT, etc.) with this solution? Ideally the `/restapi` "endpoint" (content handler) would be protected from the outside world...thoughts?

Comment: Answer for question (3) : Yes. Move your content handler to a HTTPS server block , more details can be found from [HERE](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) . For authentication you can try [ngx_http_auth_basic_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_basic_module.html) , [ngx_http_access_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html) , or [nginx-clojure access handler](http://nginx-clojure.github.io/configuration.html#26-nginx-access-handler)

Answer (score 1):

There is no API out of the box. You have to write some endpoint-snippets and use variables in your upstream config.

Take a look at:

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#readme

It's fairly simple.